# How do I compute a list intersection in Clojure?

Tags: list, clojure, intersection

I need a function that takes two lists, e.g. (1 2 3 4) and (2 3 4 5), and returns their intersection, i.e. (2 3 4). I wrote up a function that works but it's 8 lines long and very "un-Clojurelike," owing to my newness to the sport. I know there's something elegant out there, hell, maybe even a Clojure keyword that solves the whole problem.
The comparison needs to only be at the top level, not recursing through the entire list structures.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is built-in library for set operation if you don't mind the sequence of result set.

```
(require '[clojure.set :as set])
(set/intersection (set '(1 2 3 4) ) (set '( 3 4 5)))   ; ==> returns #{4 3}
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the standard answer above, if for some reason you need to retain the original order you could use a technique like this:

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(let [a       [1 2 3 4]
      b       [3 4 5]
      result  (filterv (set a) b) ]
  (is= result [3 4]))
```

based on my favorite [template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  Please see also the [list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), especially the Clojure CheatSheet.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I posted my question, I took another stab at it, and came up with this in a day:

```
(defmacro FindAtomInList [A L] `(first (drop-while #(not= ~A %) ~L)))   ;; If Atom A is in List L, return it, otherwise, nil.
(defn Intersect [L1 L2] (filter some? (map #(FindAtomInList % L1) L2))) ;; Return the intersection of Lists 1 and 2. Empty if none.
```

Thank you for your help. The repl is an amazing development tool. I like the idea of a library for set operation. I should have guessed there was such a thing.